# accessing innerHTML with jquery syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have the text within this textarea disappear when a user clicks inside it:

HTML:

```
Details:<br><textarea rows = "9" cols = "35" id = "bigtext"> the more details the better </textarea>
```

Javascript/jquery:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bigtext").focus(function(){
        $("#bigtext").hide().innerHTML; 
    });
});
```

This just hides the entire textarea and spoil the arrangement of other elements in the page... help please... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.innerHTML` is for DOM elements, the jQuery equivalent is `.html()`

Comment: Why don't you just use a `placeholder` instead of changing the contents?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of the textare as an empty string. You need to use .val() to set/get the value of form elements which includes textareas

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bigtext").focus(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

`$("#bigtext").hide()` hides the textarea itself, and it returns a jQuery object which does not have the innerHTML property so that part does not do anything

---

If you want to display a default text in the textarea, it will be better to use [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-placeholder).